# Which countable sets don't drastically change the definable topologies on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory

For $\mathcal{M}$ an expansion of $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, let $\tau^\mathcal{M}_A$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the sets definable in $\mathcal{M}$ with parameters from $A$. Say that $\mathcal{M}$ is **restrained** iff for every $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ there is a $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau_A^\mathcal{M}=\tau_B^\mathcal{R}$. Given $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, let $\mathcal{R}_U=(\mathbb{R};+,\times,U)$.

I'm interested in which sets $U$ yield restrained expansions. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}$ does not but $\{2^z:z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ does; see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155603/does-naming-the-integers-in-mathbbr-times-change-the-definable-topolo) for more detail on this point. Intuitively, very "sparse" countable sets seem likely to be restrained. To keep things hopefully manageable, let me focus on the following:

> What are the *countable closed* sets $U$ such that $\mathcal{R}_U$ is restrained?

In particular, is there a non-d-minimal countable closed set $U$ such that $\mathcal{R}_U$ is restrained?